# JAX-WS serialization into stream

Tags: java, soap, cxf, jax-ws, axis

In my project we are implementing a new feature which involves talking to a web service. I wanted to do this with JAX-WS, since it seemed to be the easiest and the way all the tutorials do it.

Now we already have some web service calls in our application, but those use Axis 1.4 and because Axis ships its own implementations of some classes (Service, QName), I experience some classloader problems when I try to talk to the new web service with JAX-WS.

I thought about just replacing Axis with the jre-builtin JAX-WS RI, but we use Axis to serialize the request into a byte array, which we then send to some other system, somehow.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// provide an AXIS configuration which overwrites the default HTTP
// handler with our handler
// implementation which writes the SOAP message into the given output
// stream.
SimpleProvider config = new SimpleProvider();
config.deployTransport("http", new SimpleTargetedChain(new ByteArraySender(outStream)));

ArchiveService service = new ArchiveServiceLocator(config);
Archive archive = service.getArchive()
archive.archiveReportWithDefTags(metaData, dataHandler);
return outStream.toString(HTTPConstants.HEADER_DEFAULT_CHAR_ENCODING);
```

Is it possible to do something similar (serialize request to local variable/stream) with either JAX-WS RI or CXF? I'd prefer to use these two over Axis2, since I read a few times on SO that they are to be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same problem, I found solutions for both CXF and Metro (JAX-WS RI), but neither of them ended up in my application, because they lead me into classpath hell. Instead I went with the old Axis (1.x), because it just works.

## CXF

For CXF I needed to register a custom ConduitInitiator in the Bus. The ConduitInitiator would save the request into an OutputStream in a custom Conduit.

The class for configuration/setup:

```
import javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager;

public class ArchiveMessageSerializer {

    public String serializeArchiveReportWithDefTags(ArchiveMetadataType metaData) throws Exception {
        final SavingConduit savingConduit = new SavingConduit();
        registerCustomTransport(savingConduit);
        try {
            final Service service = new Service();
            final Port port = service.getArchive(new MTOMFeature(true));
            port.someMethod(metaData);
        }
        finally {
            tearDownBusWithCustomTransport();
        }
        return savingConduit.getResult().toString("iso-8859-1");
    }

    private void registerCustomTransport(Conduit conduit) {
        Bus bus = BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();

        CustomConduitInitiator customTransport = new CustomConduitInitiator(conduit);

        ConduitInitiatorManager cim = bus.getExtension(ConduitInitiatorManager.class);

        cim.registerConduitInitiator("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http", customTransport);
        cim.registerConduitInitiator("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http", customTransport);
    }

    private void tearDownBusWithCustomTransport() {
        BusFactory.setThreadDefaultBus(null);
    }
}
```

The conduit initiator:

```
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.service.model.EndpointInfo;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiator;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceType;

class CustomConduitInitiator implements ConduitInitiator {

    private final Conduit fMyConduit;

    public CustomConduitInitiator(Conduit conduit) {
        fMyConduit = conduit;
    }

    @Override
    public Conduit getConduit(EndpointInfo targetInfo, Bus bus) throws IOException {
        return fMyConduit;
    }

    @Override
    public Conduit getConduit(EndpointInfo localInfo, EndpointReferenceType target, Bus bus) throws IOException {
        return fMyConduit;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getUriPrefixes() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getTransportIds() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The conduit:

```
import org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.message.MessageImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.MessageObserver;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceType;

class SavingConduit implements Conduit {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream fOutputStream;

    private Exchange fExchange;
    private MessageObserver fObserver;

    SavingConduit() {
        fOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream getResult() {
        return fOutputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare(Message message) throws IOException {
        fExchange = message.getExchange();
        message.setContent(OutputStream.class, fOutputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public void close(Message message) throws IOException {
        final OutputStream outputStream = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();

            message.put(Message.RESPONSE_CODE, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);

            final Message inMessage = new MessageImpl();
            inMessage.put(Message.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD, "GET");
            inMessage.setContent(InputStream.class, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
            inMessage.setExchange(fExchange);
            fExchange.setInMessage(inMessage);
            fObserver.onMessage(inMessage);
        }

        final InputStream inputStream = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public EndpointReferenceType getTarget() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessageObserver(MessageObserver observer) {
        fObserver = observer;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageObserver getMessageObserver() {
        return fObserver;
    }
}
```

## Metro

For Metro I had to register my TransportTubeFactory as a service. Metro would pick up my class and use it as a candidate factory to create my Tube, which is Metro's concept of a client's transport mechanism.

The file META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory:

```
com.mypackage.RedirectionTransportFactory
```

The setup code:

```
import javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature;

public class ArchiveMessageSerializer {

    public String serializeArchiveReportWithDefTags(ArchiveMetadataType metaData) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        RedirectionTransportFactory.getRegistry().registerRedirectionInThread(buffer);
        final Service service = new Service();
        final Port port = service.getPort(new MTOMFeature());
        port.someMethod(metaData);
        return buffer.toString("iso-8859-1");
    }
}
```

The transport factory:

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Tube;

public class RedirectionTransportFactory extends TransportTubeFactory {
    private static final RedirectionTransportRegistry REGISTRY = new RedirectionTransportRegistry();

    public static RedirectionTransportRegistry getRegistry() {
        return REGISTRY;
    }

    @Override
    public Tube doCreate(ClientTubeAssemblerContext context) {
        return getRegistry().createTubeFor(context);
    }
}
```

My registry for output streams:

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.ClientTubeAssemblerContext;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Tube;

public class RedirectionTransportRegistry {
    private final ThreadLocal<RegisteredTube> fCurrentThreadTube = new ThreadLocal<RegisteredTube>();

    Tube createTubeFor(ClientTubeAssemblerContext context) {
        final RegisteredTube registeredTube = fCurrentThreadTube.get();
        if (registeredTube == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return registeredTube.createTube(context);
    }

    public void registerRedirectionInThread(OutputStream outputStream) {
        final RegisteredTube registeredTube = new RegisteredTube(outputStream);
        fCurrentThreadTube.set(registeredTube);
    }

    private class RegisteredTube {

        private final OutputStream fOutputStream;

        public RegisteredTube(OutputStream outputStream) {
            fOutputStream = outputStream;
        }

        Tube createTube(ClientTubeAssemblerContext context) {
            return new RedirectionTube(context.getCodec(), fOutputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

The tube that just writes the message into the given output stream:

```
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;

import com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Packet;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Codec;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.NextAction;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.TubeCloner;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl;

public class RedirectionTube extends AbstractTubeImpl {

    private final Codec fCodec;
    private final OutputStream fOutputStream;

    public RedirectionTube(Codec codec, OutputStream outputStream) {
        fCodec = codec;
        fOutputStream = outputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractTubeImpl copy(TubeCloner cloner) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public NextAction processRequest(Packet request) {
        return doReturnWith(process(request));
    }

    @Override
    public NextAction processResponse(Packet response) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("MyAbstractTubeImpl's processException shouldn't be called.");
    }

    @Override
    public NextAction processException(Throwable t) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("MyAbstractTubeImpl's processException shouldn't be called.");
    }

    @Override
    public void preDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public Packet process(Packet p) {
        try {
            fCodec.encode(p, fOutputStream);

            return p.createClientResponse(null);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

Even though CXF has better documentation, it was easier to actually implement the Metro version once I knew about the META-INF file and which class to implement (the TransportTubeFactory). CXF has a much more complicated pipeline with interceptors that all work on the same message, whereas Metro uses a cleaner network stack-like architecture with its tubes.

I think despite them being able to do this kind of thing, none of them are really suited to actually do it. Because they are hidden behind the JAX-WS API, they are hard to configure. And depending on which implementation is shipped with your JRE, you will get into classpath hell.